# Webpack - Materialize with Symfony

Tags: symfony, webpack, materialize, symfony4

I'm running a project on Symfony. I want to use for the first Time, Symfony 4, Webpack and Vagrant/Homestead.

My host is a Windows 10
My project is host on a VM made with vagrant/Homestead on Debian
Wabpack (yarn) is installed

So,

I've made an "assets" folder
inside I have a "css" folder, a "js" folder and a "scss" folder.

I've run the command

> yarn add materialize-css

And then I run

> yarn encore dev --watch

(ofc I've run yarn install previously)

But when I run my Symfony Website... Materialize is not detected.. 
My console show me the followings errors :

> GET http://website.test/build/app.css/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
>   Found) (index):16
>
> GET http://website.test/build/manifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
>   Found) favicon.ico:1
>
> GET http://website.test/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Here is My base template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{ asset("build/app.css") }}/>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="grey">It works !</h1>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>button</a>

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src={{ asset("build/app.js") }}></script>
        <script src={{ asset("build/manifest.js") }}></script>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

I don't know what to do what can do my website working ?

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the files are really build, or whether the URL is incorrect?

Comment: The manifest.js is the only one not present... But webpack have to generate this one no ?

Comment: So, `app.js` exists? And you provided proper hints for the routing, such that Symfony knows where to look for that file?

Comment: Yes app.js exists. i didn't remember doing somehong special for the route...

Comment: I've tried to reset my project I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still not working you can try this:

```
<script src={{ asset("./build/app.js") }}></script>
<script src={{ asset("./build/runtime.js") }}></script>

<script src={{ asset("./build/vendors~app.js") }}></script>
//  for style
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{ asset("./build/app.css") }}/>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !

You have to do :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("build/app.css") }}"/>
```

And not :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{ asset("build/app.css") }}/>
```