# Webpack Encore : Files are correctly generated but server return 404 error

Tags: apache, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I've intalled and configured webpack encore on a 4.3 Symfony app. CSS an JS are generated and path looks good but php return a 404 error on those files.

It work in another app, but cannot figure where is the problem

I put files in `assets/css` and `asset/js`. 
When I run `yarn run encore dev` files are correctly copied to `public/build/css` and `public/build/js`

here is the output :

```
 4 files written to public/build
Entrypoint js/app = js/app.css js/app.js
Entrypoint css/cover = css/cover.css
```

here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // the public path you will use in Symfony's asset() function - e.g. asset('build/some_file.js')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // the following line enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/cover', './assets/css/cover.css')

;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

The way I call files in base.html.twig :

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('css/cover') }}
```

and

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/app') }}
```

And my webpack_encore.yaml

```
webpack_encore:
    # The path where Encore is building the assets.
    # This should match Encore.setOutputPath() in webpack.config.js.
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'
```

I expect the console of my brother stop showing

`GET https://louboulangerie.fr/build/css/cover.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Thanks

Edit : After days of searching, I found that if I disable the rewrite rule to https in my vhost, everything is fine. Any idea on how should I proceed ?

Comment: try with this and tell me .setPublicPath('/public/build')

Comment: I tried `.setPublicPath('/public/build')` and `.setPublicPath('public/build')` but nothing changed :/

Comment: How do you run your project ? with symfony server "127.0.0.1:8000" or http://localhost/my_project/public/index.php  ?

Comment: I run it throught the real address "https://louboulangerie.fr". I can't dev on my local computer.

Comment: I aded an edit : found that the rewrite rule to https was the problem. If anyone know why please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the entry name is the problem.

Change this :

```
.addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addStyleEntry('css/cover', './assets/css/cover.css')
```

to this :

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addStyleEntry('cover', './assets/css/cover.css')
```

Then import your assets like this:

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('cover') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

---

Furthermore, unless you really need it, you don't need to add a special style entry.
Doing this will have the same result :

<kbd>**webpack.config.js**</kbd>

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

<kbd>**app.js**</kbd>

```
// I prefer to use import instead of require
import "../css/cover.scss";
```

<kbd>**base.html.twig**</kbd>

```
<head>
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
</head>
<body>
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can't comment so I'm goignt to write an answer.

Few months ago I've [had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572157/webpack-materialize-with-symfony).
I was not doinf as you inside my twig. What I did was something like
for exemple :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("build/app.css") }}"/>
```

This work for me. Maybe try to do this way could work for you ?

Comment: I don't think that it's the problem.
`{{ encore_entry_link_tags('cover') }}` render that link : 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/cover.css">` which look nice to me. don't understand where the problem is